# How to write an ethereum smart contract to pass data among two computers only?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, private-blockchain

I have written a simple smart contract. I'm running it using rinkeby testnet. But the problem is that any machine can access  and see the data. But I need only to send the data to a specific machine( Think of an organization).

Comment: I don't exactly know your use-case. you can simply go for a private ethereum net?

Comment: check out quorum

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should consider to use an  [Ethereum private network](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Private-network) or other permissioned blockchain technologies, e.g. [Hyperledger](https://www.hyperledger.org/). Indeed, Ethereum (as well as Bitcoin) is a permissionless (i.e. without authentication) blockchain, that means that potentially every machine in the network can access to the data of the smart contract.